# Is it possible to access div content to store in database

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="textBox" contenteditable="true" name="telugu">
```

I have written above code for div.I need store entered information in database. I am able to access textbox and textarea content.Is it possible to access div area content? I must use div only because some other code is linked with div.Please help.[image]

Comment: whats the editor you are using ?

Comment: i have taken just html page.div above icons are images.i have written javascript for each and every functionalities.

Comment: $('#textBox').html(); // then post that value with ajax?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What server technologies (LAMP, Windows...) are you using?

Comment: if is that some richtext editor, then probalby this div was replaced by iframe. and to get content of iframe use `$("iframe").contents();`

Comment: There's no jQuery tag in the question.

Comment: I just used only java script and html

Comment: if is div with pure javascript then use 'document.getElementById('MyDiv1').innerHTML;' to get content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the little information you provide I can only give the most obvious answer:

```
var html = document.getElementById("textBox").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the text inside a div, i suggest you use jquery/js

```
var divContent = $("#textBox").text();
```